# Combing rows based on a count, adding values

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the dilemma: I have a table with rows. I need to count based on frequency of a certain value (in the eMail column), and then ADD numbers in certain column (cost)... as an example

```
mail           cost
me@me.com      10
me@me.com      5
john@john.com  3
me@me.com      7
john@john.com  2
```

So I need to group rows based on the email address, and add the numbers in the grouped rows "cost" column. The results should come out as an array:

```
email          frequency  totalCost
me@me.com      3          22
john@john.com  2          5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a single SQL query.

```
SELECT
    email,
    COUNT(email) AS frequency,
    SUM(cost) AS totalCost
FROM
    emails
GROUP BY
    email
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to try:

```
INSERT INTO frequency (mail, frequency, cost)
SELECT mail, COUNT(*), SUM(cost) FROM mail GROUP BY mail;
```

This assumes:

`mail` is a table containing your first data set
`frequency` is the table you wish to enter your aggregate values.

Let us know if this works :)

[edit/additional]:
These are the table definitions I assumed:

```
CREATE TABLE mail (
      mail VARCHAR(50)
    , cost INT
);

CREATE TABLE frequency (
      mail VARCHAR(50)
    , frequency INT
    , cost INT
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should work:

```
SELECT email, COUNT(*) AS frequency, SUM(cost) AS totalCost
FROM your_table
GROUP BY email
```

Then, you fetch it in PHP with whatever API you use. These are basics, in theory you should be able to come up with those solutions on your own if you are ready to make an application.